# How to connect to remote SQL Server present in a windows machine using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, remote-access

I have remote windows machine which contains a SQL server and this windows machine can be accessed only using my company VPN. Now I want to connect to this SQL server from node.js. I am trying different methods but it always shows me same error,

**ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 15.212.165.75:1433 in 15000ms**

I only have windows authentication credentials of the SQL server.

Is there any way to connect to this SQL server?

Comment: Have you recorded a network trace using Wireshark?

Comment: No, may I know what is the use of network tracing?

Comment: So you can see _exactly_ what your NodeJS program is trying to connect to and how Windows (and your VPN client) is directing (i.e. _routing_) the connection attempt.

Comment: Also, have you verified that you can connect to the SQL Server instance using other software like SSMS?

Comment: Verify the port is reachable from your client machine using telnet or powershell.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to SQL server using SSMS inside the remote windows machine. But I want to make connection to SQL server from another computer.

Comment: Is the remote machine configured to allow incoming connections to SQL Server? There could be firewall rules to prevent it, or the SQL Server service itself may only be listening on the localhost addresses (127.0.0.1 for IPv4 or ::1 for IPv6).

Answer (score 0):

From your description "I only have windows authentication credentials of the SQL server.". I don't remember Node JS has any way to do Windows Auth, maybe there is some new module I don't know. Your best bet will be make the SQL Server "Mix Mode", which allow regular user. I was able to do what you try to do recent ly with "mssql" package. Below is the coding for package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "mssql": "^8.1.2"
  },
```

This link is the npm for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
Just use the sample code there, it should connect.